# unable to set printer driver IP address with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on updating printer driver ports.

with my powershell script, I was able to add a port, attach it to the printer driver. however, when I look at the port list for the printer driver shows as not selected . in fact still showing old port selected.

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name "ipaddress" -PrinterHostAddress "ipaddress" -ComputerName "pcname"
Get-Printer -ComputerName pcname
 | Where-Object {$_.PortName -eq "ipaddress"} | Set-Printer -PortName "ipaddress"
Remove-PrinterPort -Name "ipaddress"
```

Comment: Move the pipeline to the same line as `Get-Printer`

Comment: Riley Carney, we have to assume that this was just a post error, because, if this is the code, it'd error off immediately, and obviously show as an error in the editor. He says, he is not getting the assignment at all, and the port needed is not selected, which does not match his statement [I was able to add a port and attach it to the printer driver], if the port never changed.

Comment: Jamal, just do a simple Get-Printer and Get-PrinterPort on the target host,  to see what the full list shows. If you are saying the port was never assigned then the Add-PrinterPort did not work. Also, why are you removing a port you just created?

Comment: thank you all for your response. Riley, Postanote is correct on the pipeline. it seem when the target computer is windows 10 . this script has no problem. but when it is a windows 7 pro or enterprise that is when I get errror. BTW the last line is removing the old printer port. Again thank you all.

Comment: today coworker mentioned it won't work on windows 7 because , W7 has powershell 2 which doesn't understand above code. I might have to install winrm 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to reset my printer when it gets re-added to the network (I don't use it often, so my router usually assigns it a different IP).

```
$printerMac = "30-cd-a7-fb-13-85"
$driverName = "Samsung C1810 Series"
$ipSpace = "192.168.1.*"

$printerPort = Get-NetNeighbor | where LinkLayerAddress -eq $printerMac | select -First 1
if($null -eq $printerPort){
    "Printer not found on network." 
    exit 1;
}
$printDriver = Get-PrinterDriver -Name $driverName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(-not $printDriver){
    Write-Warning "Printer driver is not installed"
    exit 1;
}

Get-Printer | where Name -eq $driverName | Remove-Printer

Restart-Service spooler

Get-PrinterPort | where Name -like $ipSpace | Remove-PrinterPort -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Add-PrinterPort -Name $printerPort.IpAddress -PrinterHostAddress $printerPort.IpAddress
"Added printer port"

Add-Printer -Name $driverName -PortName $printerPort.IpAddress -DriverName $driverName
```

I find it easier to remove and re-add everything. Restarting the spooler is important in that case.